# How to preview RDoc file?

Tags: github, rdoc

Want to see how an RDoc README file will look on Github before committing. How to run RDoc on a single file and preview the result in a browser?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ruby as a built-in `rdoc` cli that will generate html pages from `*.rdoc` files:

```
rdoc README.rdoc -o ./tmp/doc
```

Try `rdoc --help` for more info.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative you can use this [website](http://markup.herokuapp.com/sample) to preview Markdown, RDoc, Textile ....

Comment: Unfortunately, this website does not work anymore :'(

Comment: @JimEdelstein here is another project to preview rdoc/markdown/textile
http://markup.herokuapp.com/sample

Comment: The currently linked website doesn't work any more either